# The time-dependence of the expectation values of spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

Assume a spin s= 1/2 is subjected to an external magnetic field $B=Be_z$. The Hamiltonian is then given by
$$ \hat{H} = -\frac{eB}{mc} \hat{S}_z = w\hat{S_z} $$
and that at t= 0, the spin of the particle is in the eigenstate of the $S_x$ operator with the eigenvalue $ \hbar/2 $, e.g.
$$ \hat{S}_x|\psi (t= 0)⟩= \frac{\hbar}{2}|\psi(t= 0)⟩.$$

So first I derived the expressions for the dynamics of the spin operators and got:
$$ \frac{d\hat{S}_y^H}{dt} =  iw\hat{S}_x^H $$
$$ \frac{d\hat{S}_x^H}{dt} =  {-iw} \hat{S}_y^H $$
$$ \frac{d\hat{S}_z^H}{dt} = 0 $$

Now I want to calculate the time-dependence of the expectation values $ ⟨ \hat{S}_x ⟩ $, $ ⟨ \hat{S}_y ⟩ $ and $ ⟨ \hat{S}_z ⟩ $. To do that I used Ehrenfest theorem (for an arbitrary $S_i$:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} ⟨ S_i ⟩_H = \frac{1}{i\hbar} ⟨ [ \hat{S}_i , \hat{H} ] ⟩ + ⟨ \frac{\partial S_i }{dt} ⟩. $$

Starting with the first term:
$$ ⟨ [ \hat{S}_i , \hat{H} ] ⟩ = ⟨ {S}_i  \hat{H}  ⟩ - ⟨ \hat{H} \hat{S}_i ⟩ = w (  ⟨ \hat{U}^{\dagger} \hat{S}_i \hat{U} \hat{U}^{\dagger} \hat{S}_z \hat{U}  ⟩ - ⟨ \hat{U}^{\dagger} \hat{S}_z \hat{U} \hat{U}^{\dagger} \hat{S}_i \hat{U}  ⟩ ) =$$
$$ = w (  ⟨ \hat{U}^{\dagger} \hat{S}_i \hat{S}_z \hat{U}  ⟩ - ⟨ \hat{U}^{\dagger} \hat{S}_z \hat{S}_i \hat{U}  ⟩ ) $$

So my question is what is the best/easiest way to go now? I tried using the definition of expectation value and the fact that the state at t=0 is ( changing to z-basis ):

$$ |\psi (t= 0)⟩ = |+⟩_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |+⟩_z + |-⟩_z ) $$

So that

$$ ⟨ [ \hat{S}_i , \hat{H} ] ⟩ = \frac{w}{2} \Bigl( ⟨ ⟨+|_z + ⟨-|_z | e^{-iw\hat{S}_zt} \hat{S}_i \hat{S}_z e^{iw\hat{S}_zt} | |+⟩_z + |-⟩_z ⟩ \Bigr) $$

But I don't really know how to continue here to find the expectation value of the exponential term with t-dependence! Any advice appreciated:)

Comment: Why not using the Schrödinger pciture, where the operators do not evolve in time, while the states do? In this case the time evolution of the state is $|\psi(t)\rangle=\exp{(-iHt)}|\psi(t=0)\rangle$. If you accept this solution, I can elaborate more on a dedicated answer :)

Comment: In the Heisenberg picture you are using, Ehrenfest's theorem is a triviality. You can already establish, by inspection, that $\hat S_x^H$ and  $\hat S_y^H$ rotate into each other with frequency $w /\hbar$, in your *highly* nonstandard notation, so you are done.

Comment: @Matteo Of course! I'm open to try multiple approaches:) but would it be easier to use Schrödinger picture in this case?

Comment: @CosmasZachos How could you see that the rotate into each other with this frequency? and how is this related to the time dependence of the expectation value of them?

Comment: The frequency is actually *w*; I set $\hbar=1$ and garbled its reintroduction. See answer.

Comment: Just one comment that for understanding the answers (that is also immensly important for quantum mechanics in general): With some function f and an operator $A$ with eigenstate $\ket{a}$ to the eigenvector a, $f(A) \ket{a} = f(a) \ket{a}$, so $e^{a H} \ket{n} = e^{a E_n} \ket{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Schrödinger picture, you can write the Hamiltonian operator in the basis of the eigenstates of $\hat{S}_z$: $|+\rangle_z=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$ and $|-\rangle_z=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right)$ as
$$
H = \frac{\hbar w}{2} \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{array}\right)
$$
and the initial state as
$$
|\psi(t=0)\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |+\rangle_z + |-\rangle_z \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right).
$$

Now from the Schrödinger equation we get the formula for the time evolution of a state:
$$
i\hbar \partial_t \psi = H \psi \rightarrow |\psi(t)\rangle = \exp{\left[-iHt/\hbar\right]} |\psi(t=0)\rangle.
$$
The matrix exponential of a diagonal matrix is trivial: you just exponentiate every diagonal term, so:
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{cc} e^{-iwt/2} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{iwt/2} \end{array}\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c}e^{-iwt/2}\\e^{iwt/2}\end{array}\right).
$$
Knowing the time evolved state, you can compute expectation values of any operator, including for instance
$$\hat{S}_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
\hat{S}_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{array}\right)
:$$
$$
\langle \psi(t) | \hat{S}_x | \psi(t) \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{2} \cos{(wt)}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
\langle \psi(t) | \hat{S}_y | \psi(t) \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sin{(wt)}
$$

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Ahh that was very helpful! Appreciate the help:) but I have one question about the matrix exponential, you replaced the H in the exponent with w instead of wS_z, should not S_z also be in the matrix representation of the time operator?

Comment: I have actually computed $\exp{(-iHt/\hbar)} = \exp{(-i \frac{wt}{2} S_z)}$, then I have exponentiated the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}{(-iwt/2, +iwt/2})$, which is a diagonal matrix having the exponential of the eigenvalues as diagonal elements

Answer (score 3):

Since you are working in the Heisenberg picture where states are time-independent, you may automatically take expectation values of your operator equations, resulting in the same uniform rotation structure,
$$ \frac{d \langle \hat{S}_y^H\rangle }{dt} =  iw  \langle \hat{S}_x^H\rangle , \\
 \frac{d \langle \hat{S}_x^H\rangle }{dt} = - iw  \langle \hat{S}_y^H\rangle  ,\\
 \frac{d \langle \hat{S}_z^H \rangle }{dt} = 0 .$$

In your  notation, their evident solution is
$$   \langle \hat{S}_y^H (t)\rangle  =  \cos( wt ) \langle \hat{S}_y^H(0)\rangle +  \sin(wt ) \langle \hat{S}_x^H(0)\rangle , \\
 \langle \hat{S}_x^H (t)\rangle  =  \cos(wt ) \langle \hat{S}_x^H(0)\rangle -  \sin(  wt ) \langle \hat{S}_y^H(0)\rangle ,
 \\
   \langle \hat{S}_z^H (t)\rangle  =  \langle \hat{S}_z^H (0)\rangle   .$$

Comment: So I could've got the answer by integrating my equations!:D I totally missed that, thank you so much for your help sir!:)

Comment: Indeed, Ehrenfest's theorem is a triviality in the Heisenberg picture...